# Purposely return all records with LIKE clause

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a project that uses a `LIKE` query that is dynamically generated to match results in the mysql DB.

Some of the search filters (for example 'Status') include a the following dropdown:

```
 <select name="status">
       <option value="inactive"> 
  ...
```

This `value` of this dropdown essentially injects in to the `LIKE` statement and returns the appropriate records for that filter. The problem is I need to add an `all` option that will return **all** records for every filter (in this case ALL statuses, active, inactive, etc).

My question is, is it possible to create an option such as:

`<option value="*"> All </option>`

Which will generate something similar to the following query, and return all 'status' records:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE status LIKE '%*%'
```

My goal is to not have to hardcode an additional PHP condition for every filter I need an `All` option for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't put anything between `%%`

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM records
 WHERE status LIKE '%%';
                    ^^
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60d2d/3)** demo

---

Now the important question **why** are you using `LIKE` when you're dealing with a list of predefined options? **Stop! Don't do that.** Using `LIKE` in such manner prevents MySQL from using any index you might have on this column effectively causing a full scan every time you query your data.

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: The options are not predefined, they are generated on the fly, its hard to explain.

Comment: At least don't use a wildcard on the left side if possible. Meaning do this `LIKE 'inactive%'` instead of `LIKE '%inactive%'`

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'abc' like "%%%" -- >1

<option value="%"> All </option>
```

Comment: +1, Good answer, because I have to put something in the value field for it to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you organize your query with conditions that will short-circuit the `LIKE` statement all-together if you don't need it.

You could do something like this in php:

```
$query = "WHERE true ";

if($status != "all")
   $query .= " AND status LIKE '%".$status."%'";
if($some_other_filter != "all")
   $query .= " AND some_other_filter LIKE '%".$some_other_filter."%'";
// .. and so on
```

Of course, as far as structuring your code you could use an associative array for all the filters and just write a loop:

```
$query = "WHERE true ";    

foreach($filters_array as $filter => $value)
{
    if($value != "all")
       $query .= " AND $filter LIKE '%".$value."%'";
}
```

And if you don't want to put the conditions in PHP you could do the short-circuit in the SQL query:

```
foreach($filters_array as $filter => $value)
{        
    $query .= " AND ($filter LIKE '%".$value."%' OR $value = 'all')";
}
```